# How to unpack CHIME/FRB data files?

Tags: python, msgpack

[Depiction of a Fast Radio Burst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlZck.jpg)

I have an issue with the msgpack.py which has to be used to read and uncompress the msgpack data.  Here is the location of the files which I'm trying to uncompress [CHIME/FRB data files](https://www.canfar.net/storage/list/AstroDataCitationDOI/CISTI.CANFAR/19.0005/data/180814).  Here is additional information if you can help me.  [PyPi msgpack](https://pypi.org/project/msgpack/).

Does anyone here have experience in trying to read the CHIME/FRB data files and if so can you explain the process?

```
 import msgpack
 from io import BytesIO

 buf = BytesIO()
 for i in range(100):
   buf.write(msgpack.packb(i, use_bin_type=True))

 buf.seek(0)

 unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(buf, raw=False)
 for unpacked in unpacker:
    print(unpacked)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no difficulties to unpack the "astro" data. The only difficulty is that the data is huge... and contains other (unspecified) binary data.

Here is how I successfully unpack the file "astro_10889573_20180814144950703901_beam1180_00161339_01.msgpack":

```py
import pprint
import msgpack

data_msgpack = "astro_10889573_20180814144950703901_beam1180_00161339_01.msgpack"
with open(data_msgpack, mode="rb") as fd:
    data = msgpack.unpack(fd)

pprint.pprint(data)
```

The starting of the output is:

```py
['assembled_chunk in msgpack format',
 1,
 0,
 16777216,
 1180,
 16,
 16,
 384,
 64,
 65536,
 16777216,
 63441076224,
 393216,
 1,
 b'T\xb2\xc1?z\xd1\xd4?bs\xd1?\xed\xf5\xc4?\xaf#\xc7?`\x92\xd4?\xc7L\xd5?'
 b'\x00\x15\xcb?\x14\xb0\xbf?M\xec\xd2?6\xea\xd1?\xe1N\xcb?*\x12\xca?'
 b'\x9e\xf1\xd2?\xa39\xd3?\xab\x9d\xe4?z\xb2\xd3?\xcdg\xdd?\xedc\xdc?:\xd4\xd4?'
 b'"\xbf\xdb?A$\xd1?))\xd0?EE\xc1?o \xcb?g$\xca?\xd7\x7f\xce?\xe3\x9e\xde?'
 b'J\xa0\xdc?O\xef\xd7?\x07P\xd9?(a\xe0?\xa8V\xdb?;\xb9\xe0?\xdbY\xd6?'
 b'\x8a\xb8\xe4?eI\xe5?\x0eu\xea?\xca\xac\xec?\xb8\xe1\xcf?\xa0\x97\xd2?'
 b'\xf1\xd9\xdb?\xa7I\xd8?\xde\xb5\xc1?\xb6\x02\xc2?$\x08\xc6?1\x84\xcb?'
 b'\x1d\x84\xcb?\x94\xb2\xd3?M=\xd9?\xd5\x87\xdb?\xcc\xea\xce?M\xd7\xcb?|9\xda?'
 b'\xc6\x02\xda?\x04-\xdb?\x99\xf1\xcf?\\\xa3\xdb?\xf39\xde?\xce\x9a\xd3?'
 b'm\xec\xe2?j\xac\xdd?\xdf\xa8\xd3?Gj\xd0?H\xe6\x0b?\xd2I\n?\x7f\x01\x00?'
 b'\xa9\xfb\xf4>\xdb\xf1\xf1>\xe0\xff\x03?\x9c\xb9\x04?\xf7\x08\xef>'
 b'\xc4\x84\x05?TZ\xeb>\xd0\x1c\x01?\xb0.\xfb>\xfd \x08?\x8f~\xf8>\xef\x19\xff>'
 b'<\x9e\t?0\xd0\xdb>\x89+\xdd>R\xad\x05?\x03*\x00?Z\xd0\x08?M\x82\x17?Ba\xf1>'
 b'\xd4i\xf1>\xa7\xeb\xef>\x83\x13\x0c?Hq\xf4>\xf51\x1a?\x815\xf8>\x94\xd7\x01?'
 b'E\xb8\x07?/\xfa\t?\x83\x9a\xee>\xd3\xce\xf3>\x94Q\xfe>9\t\xd9>\xf9n\x02?'
 b"\x81'\xf3>}O\xef>\n\xd0\x0c?\x04\n\x08?5\xff\xdf>\xb1\xb1\x0c?\x9d\xda\x06?"
 b'\x8fO\xf5>>\xa7\xf3>\x13\xc9\x0c?\xc1B\x06?t\xbd\xea>{\xc2\x01?\x00\x0c\x08?'
 b'\x1e\xf3\x03?\x98\xf3\xfa>\xcfn\n?c\x08\x04?pV\x04?3Y\x17?\xf5\x86\xf4>'
 b'\xc6\xd2\xec>\x9b\x9c\x04?Y\xed\xf2>\x08\x95\x00?\xbe\x15\t?\xc2H\xf0>'
 b'%&\x1b?$\x0e\x0b?\x03$\x07?\xd3R(?\x1a\xc4\xfe>O!\x0f?\x93](?p\x07\x13?'
 b"\xe2U\x06?\t\x89'?\x95\xf6\x1f?\x06\xed\r?\xbag\x04?w\xd2\x07?7\xe9\x1a?"
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent LAPORTE for the quick response.  However I'm getting this error what could it be?                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unpacker.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open(data_msgpack, mode="rb") as fd:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\chime\\Python381\x07stro_10889573_20180814144950703901_beam1180_00161339_01.msgpack'

Comment: line 5 as fd should that be different?

Comment: You need to give the full path of your file. In my exemple it is in the same path as the current working directory.

Comment: Ok lol I fixed the path my bad but now this error.  OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Python381\\chime\x07stro_10889573_20180814144950703901_beam1180_00161339_01.msgpack'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unpacker.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open(data_msgpack, mode="rb") as fd:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Python381\\chime\x07stro_10889573_20180814144950703901_beam1180_00161339_01.msgpack'

Comment: Use "\\" instead of "\"

Comment: THANKS A BUNCH U DA MAN

Comment: My status is to little for upvotes.  So I unpacked it whats next can I use it in a program that will make sense out of the file?